# good data structure for finding intersections of out-of-order value arrays in an inverted index?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, inverted-index

I have an inverted index, in which each token maps to a list of pairs `(document_id, score)`. Each token's value list is sorted by descending score, so the highest ranked documents are first.

Unfortunately, for my application it is impossible to guarantee that sorted-by-score will also be sorted-by-id for all tokens simultaneously, as the score is adjusted based on the token's context in the document. For example, if my "documents" are the strings "wine-red iPhone" with `(id, score) = (1, 105)` and "red wine" with `(id, score) = (2, 100)`, "red" and "wine" have equal importance in "red wine", but "wine" < "red" < "iPhone" in importance in "wine-red iPhone", so the scores might be adjusted so that the inverted index looks like

```
"red"    -> [(2, 100), (1, 95)]
"wine"   -> [(1, 105), (2, 100)]
"iPhone" -> [(1, 115)]
```

I need to find intersections of these lists on the ids, to return a ranked list of document ids which all contain some set of tokens (standard search problem). In the example above, suppose there is another document "white wine" with id=3 and score=50, so the inverted index now looks like this:

```
"red"    -> [(2, 100), (1, 95)]
"wine"   -> [(1, 105), (2, 100), (3, 50)]
"white"  -> [(3, 50)]
"iPhone" -> [(1, 115)]
```

Then, if the search tokens are `{"red", "wine"}`, the problem is essentially to pull the values of the two tokens, in this case `[(2, 100), (1, 95)]` and `[(1, 105), (2, 100), (3, 50)]` and intersect them on the document id, so the result is something like `[(2, f(100, 100)), (1, f(95, 105))]`. `f` is some averaging function, doesn't matter.

It needs to be fast, and consume as little memory as possible (disk space is not a problem, however). In some cases it will store millions of unique tokens mapping to tens of millions of unique document ids.

To try to meet my constraints so far, I've wound up storing the data in a trie modified to be a key-value store (where each `(id, score)` pair is one value), essentially for the compression in memory. `inverted_index.get(token)` iterates over the array and returns a hash map of `id -> score`, and `get` can also take such a hash map as an argument so the intersection is done while iterating over the array and assembling the next map. There are a few other minor optimizations around partitioning the lists into primary and fallback lists, serialization/deserialization, blah blah blah. They're all sort of bandaids that don't address the bigger issue, that I'm not really using the right data structure and algorithms for the problem. Currently, my largest use case has about 20m unique document ids and takes about 400mb when fully loaded into memory.

At the moment, this is the biggest bottleneck in performance in my application, especially when a set of tokens contains some tokens with a very large number of values. I'm open to using an existing library, writing something from scratch, optimizations to the current method, etc. My main stack is in python, but this part is written in C++ and Cython. I'm open to any language, if you know of an existing source, so long as I can write Python wrappers around it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you explain this a little more clearly? Write a clear example of your inputs and outputs. I don't understand what "the intersection of these lists" means.

Comment: @robertking done, hope it's clearer now? thanks for the feedback.

Comment: if it's impossible to guarantee that sorted-by-score will also be sorted-by-id, could you pretend they're in order and use a hashtable of the ones that are out of order to do corrections on the fly?

Comment: Usually the inverted lists of an inverted index are **sorted**. You can then easily compute intersections between those lists by different algorithms. For example a naive **zipper approach** which advances in both lists and compares the elements. Next would be **binary search** the elements from the smaller list in the longer list. Then you could combine this search with an **exponential search** which yields what is called **galloping search** and so on. Many universities have **information retrieval** courses that teach those stuff and some even have their recordings available to public.

Comment: @Zabuza yes, I know about these methods, but as I say in my question I cannot guarantee that the items are sorted by id, as I need them sorted by descending score for my application.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, when storing inverted indices, the list of documents for a token is stored in a simple array sorted by document id, and the array is compressed in some way to ensure that document ids take up the least possible space. Then intersection can be done blazing fast by decoding, scanning and merging the sorted arrays, where the bulk of the work happens in the CPU cache. E.g. see this library https://github.com/lemire/JavaFastPFOR - I suggest to start exploring from here and read the relevant papers referenced there.

Comment: I guess maybe my best bet is to figure out a way to work around the constraint that currently does not let me sort by document id, and then that would let me use one of these tried-and-true methods. I was worried that would be the answer :) Thanks for the helpful link.

Comment: I think sorting by descending score is fine too - as long as all documents are sorted in the same order, you can apply sorted merge. Just use concatenation(score, document id) as your sort key.

Comment: "as long as all documents are sorted in the same order".    

They're not. The score is a function of the document score and the token's context in the document. See the first example in my question. That's the difficulty of the problem.

Comment: Oh I see. Then it sounds like your program already does sorting documents by context-dependent score for every token, and it'll probably be better off simply not doing that, keeping documents sorted by id for fast intersection, and doing sort-by-score afterwards :)